# Set Active 'false' not working in custom tab in magento admin customer edit page

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, backend, tabs

I have successfully added a custom tab in `customer_edit_tabs` section and is ordered after `orders` tab.

However when I go to **edit customer page**, my custom tab is by default set to active instead showing me default active tab (i.e. Customer View).

I have done this so far but no luck-

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        //get all existing tabs
        $this->parent = parent::_prepareLayout();
        //add new tab
        $this->addTab('relate_order', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('relate_order')->__('Relate Order'),
            'content'   => $this->getLayout()
             ->createBlock('relate_order/adminhtml_customer_edit_tabs_relate', 'relate.order')->toHtml(),
            'after'     => 'orders',

            //setting non active not working
            'active'    => false
        ));
        return $this->parent;
    }
```

**Even though I have mentioned this new tab to be `not active`, it still shows up at first.**

Please help.

Comment: Did you try to omit the active option?

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt yes, gives me same result. Thanks

Comment: did u find a solution to this ?

Comment: No, I haven't been able to.

Answer (score 1):

To have the tab active, it either have to be the first or it has to return a boolean `true`:

```
\Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs::addTab
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Tabs.php:140
if (is_null($this->_activeTab)) $this->_activeTab = $tabId;
if (true === $this->_tabs[$tabId]->getActive()) $this->setActiveTab($tabId);
```

You don't return a boolean true, so the first case is yours. You should try to `<depends>` on `Mage_Adminhtml` to make sure, your layout xml is loaded later, and your tab is not the first.

Comment: even after declaring `<depends>` tag, giving me same results.

Comment: Then you should hook into the method and check which of the two lines adds your tab. Happy digging. I recommend xdebug.